# Convert <Anonymous Type> to Model class type in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dynamic, properties

I am using c# prog with web API new,

I have created a common return type class and it will return some list in dynamical value. I am created login control to check a password getting from SP. I am struck how yo convert to class dynamic value to the class. Please find the image. Please help me how to get haspassword and token properties

[image]

```
    {
        public dynamic ValList { get; set; }
        public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Casting is a **compile**-time thing. When you don´t know the actual type at compile-time, you can´t cast. What do you want to achieve by converting? What do you want to do with the converted object afterwards? Please provide a more meaningful example.

Comment: As per image i need to get haspassword and token  values in a string.

Comment: Maybe you could use reflection to get the properties by their names. However I´m still not sure if this is what you **should** do, as we simply don´t know **why** you want this and **why** your type even is `dynamic` at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can get password and token like this

```
string password = ObjcommonReturnTypes.ValList.ObjloginoutPutToken.HasPassword.ToString();
string token = ObjcommonReturnTypes.ValList.ObjloginoutPutToken.TokenVal.ToString();
```